# Как изменить скорость звука в gstreamer?

Tags: c++, linux, c, gstreamer

в туториалах есть пример с видео, но там меняется скорость воспроизведения, только если меняешь ползунок во время воспроизведения видео, а мне надо, чтобы поменял скорость и включил звук. чтобы он с такой скоростью работал. и вот я не могу понять как это сделать. вот как я сделал init gst.

```
static void init_sound ( ) {
        gst_init ( NULL, NULL );
        gst.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ( "radio" );
        gst.source = gst_element_factory_make ( "filesrc", NULL );
        gst.demuxer = gst_element_factory_make ( "decodebin", NULL );
        gst.decoder = gst_element_factory_make ( "audioconvert", NULL );
        gst.volume = gst_element_factory_make ( "volume", NULL );
        gst.conv = gst_element_factory_make ( "audioconvert", NULL );
        gst.sink = gst_element_factory_make ( "autoaudiosink", NULL );
        gst.speed = gst_element_factory_make ( "speed", NULL );

        gst_bin_add_many ( GST_BIN ( gst.pipeline ),
                        gst.source,
                        gst.demuxer,
                        gst.decoder,
                        gst.volume,
                        gst.conv,
                        gst.sink,
                        gst.speed,
                        NULL
                        );

        gst_element_link_many ( gst.decoder, gst.volume, gst.conv, gst.sink, gst.speed, NULL );
        gst_element_link ( gst.source, gst.demuxer );
        g_signal_connect ( gst.demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK ( gst_demuxer_pad_added_cb ), NULL );

        g_object_set ( gst.volume, "volume", 1.0, NULL );
        g_object_set ( gst.speed, "speed", 0.3, NULL );

        gst.bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus ( GST_PIPELINE ( gst.pipeline ) );
        gst_bus_add_signal_watch ( gst.bus );

        g_signal_connect ( gst.bus, "message", G_CALLBACK ( cb_message ), NULL );
}
```

вот меняю скорость, когда ползунок передвигаю.

```
static void change_speed_cb ( GtkRange *range, gpointer data ) {
        double value = gtk_range_get_value ( range );
        g_object_set ( G_OBJECT ( gst.speed ), "speed", value, NULL );
}
```

Comment: перепиши фразу "чтобы поменял скорость и включил звук. чтобы он с такой скоростью работал." не понятно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gst.sink, gst.speed` поменяй местами. Тут конвеер. У тебя сначала вывод, а потом изменение скорости. Скорость надо выставить до вывода.

Comment: блин. спасибо большое. интересно, почему это так работает, а по другому нет? я думал что они компилируются и учитывают всё. спасибо.